# OpenCV position , width and height

Tags: java, opencv

Hi there I'm using that example to detect object everything works fine I just need some more things

---

how to get:

### X-Y position

### Width - Height

---

I don't want width or height of my picture, already know those , I want the width and height of founded object for example I have character L as objectImage than I have scene with all characters than when opencv found L character in scene I want width and height of L-character in scene not in my picture

example : http://dummyscodes.blogspot.com/2015/12/using-siftsurf-for-object-recognition.html

Comment: this might be an unrelated comment, but i personally think openCV works better with python or c++, there are more examples for those languages aswell.

Comment: I don't know python or c++ that's reason I'm working on java

Comment: alright, I'm not sure if it works the same with the java lib, but you should be able to get the contours of the object you're looking for, once you have the contours of that object you can get its X-Y position, and its width  and height.

Comment: Don't link to other sites... see this [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And instead of using big and bold font, describe what x and y positions or w and h you actually want!

Comment: But I don't want width or height of my picture, already know those , I want the width and height of founded object for example I have character L as objectImage than I have scene with all characters than when opencv found L character in scene I want width and height of L-character in scene not in my picture

Answer (score 1):

If you have a an image inside a Mat object you could simply do:

```
Mat picture = new Mat(someData);
System.out.println(picture.width() + picture.height());
```

Maybe check out this tutorial?
http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02-first-java-application-with-opencv.html

And use this as reference to know what the actual C++ code does: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

Comment: But I don't want width or height of my picture,  already know those , I want the width and height of founded object for example I have character L as objectImage than I have scene with all characters than when opencv found L character in scene I want width and height of L-character in scene not in my picture